# Text rotation in slick2d

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

How can I rotate the text drawing with Unicodefont.
I can draw text using any font in this way.

```
UnicodeFont font = new UnicodeFont(fontpath,fontsize, false, false);
font.drawString(0,0,"hoge");
```

But I can not find any rotation method.
If I can convert the drawing text to Image object, I can rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kenichi.  To rotate the text, you must do the following. 
Add the following line to the top of your file in the imports: 
`import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;`
After this, you must modify your code to say this:
`UnicodeFont font = new UnicodeFont(fontpath,fontsize, false, false);`
`glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);`
`font.drawString(0,0,"hoge");`

The `glRotatef(float, float, float, float)` method is part of LWJGL and rotates on the Z axis 90 degrees.